# How can I add dynamic command in Selenium IDE?

Tags: testing, selenium, automation, selenium-ide

I am using Selenium IDE to create some Automated TCs, I have dynamical content area on my site, some time this area has content id=100 and sometimes id=101.

How can I tell selenium not to stop and try to find id=101 when the script doesn't find id=100 ?

Action = Click

Target 1:

```
//html/body/div/div/div[4]/div/div[3]/div[3]/ul/li[3]/a/div
```

If this target failed, I want selenium to use the following target:

Target 2:

```
//html/body/div/div/div[4]/div[3]/div[3]/ul/li[3]/a/div
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible in the IDE alone.

Answer (score 1):

There's probably a hack that would allow you to do this with the IDE, but you should really consider using WebDriver for this with the language of your choice (Python or Ruby are excellent options, but almost all popular languages are supported).

Comment: With Selenium IDE, how can I let Selenium continue even if the Step failed? As that may help in that case.

Comment: As mentioned in another answer, you should always use verify, not assert if you want the test to continue execution on error.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sideflow to loop and goto. https://github.com/darrenderidder/sideflow

Use verify rather than assert to let the test continue if the step fails.